# How to add a combobox for filtering vaadin Grid columns

Tags: java, combobox, grid, vaadin, vaadin7

I have to add a combobox for filtering the vaadin grid columns.The combobox will show the columns of the grid, I made a grid and getting the data from the domain class.
the code is as follows

```
 BeanItemContainer<Partner> container = new BeanItemContainer<Partner>
(Partner.class, model.getPartnerList());
            Grid grid = new Grid();


             grid.setColumns("code","surname","name","companyName");

             grid.getColumn("code").setHeaderCaption("Code");
             grid.getColumn("lastname").setHeaderCaption("Last Name");
             grid.getColumn("name").setHeaderCaption("First Name");
             grid.getColumn("companyName").setHeaderCaption("Company");

             //grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
            layout.addComponent(grid);
            addComponent(layout);
            return layout;
```

I need a comboBox with values **Code, Last Name, First Name, Company** from the grid.

Comment: Please describe more thoroughly how the filtering should work. Also have you checked the [vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html) for the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the columns from the grid and as these as the items in a ComboBox. To do this, I've defined a class `GridColumn` which represents the properties of the com.vaadin.ui.Grid.Column we are interested in (i.e. the id and the header caption):

**GridColumn.java**

```
/**
 * Represents a column in a Vaadin Grid
 */
public class GridColumn {

    private String id; // propertyId in com.vaadin.ui.Grid.Column

    private String header; // headerCaption in com.vaadin.ui.Grid.Column

    // Getters and setters omitted

}
```

The following code can then be used to construct the relevent UI components (Grid and ComboBox) and add then to the layout:

```
    // Adapted from your code
    List<Partner> partnerList = new ArrayList<Partner>();
    partnerList.add(new Partner("AB", "Smith", "James", "Company A"));
    partnerList.add(new Partner("DD", "Jones", "Robin", "Company B"));

    BeanItemContainer<Partner> container = new BeanItemContainer<Partner>(Partner.class, partnerList);

    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.setColumns("code", "surname", "name", "companyName");

    grid.getColumn("code").setHeaderCaption("Code");
    grid.getColumn("lastname").setHeaderCaption("Last Name");
    grid.getColumn("name").setHeaderCaption("First Name");
    grid.getColumn("companyName").setHeaderCaption("Company");

    grid.setContainerDataSource(container);

    // Get the list of columns and as them as ComboBox items
    List<Column> cols = grid.getColumns();
    List<GridColumn> comboItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Column column : cols) {
        GridColumn col = new GridColumn();
        col.setHeader(column.getHeaderCaption()); // Column Header Caption
        col.setId((String) column.getPropertyId()); // Column "id"
        comboItems.add(col);
    }

    // Construction of the ComboBox
    ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
    // Use the List<GridColumn> as the container for the ComboBox items
    combo.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<GridColumn>(GridColumn.class, comboItems));
    // Property of GridColumn to use as the value to display in the ComboBox
    combo.setItemCaptionPropertyId("header");

    combo.addBlurListener(e -> {
        // Upon selection of a column, update the grid to only display that column
        GridColumn selected = (GridColumn) combo.getValue();
        System.out.println("Selected value is " + selected);
        grid.setColumns(selected.getId());
        grid.getColumn(selected.getId()).setHeaderCaption(selected.getHeader());
    });

    addComponents(combo, grid);
```

A blurListener is present on the ComboBox so that when a value is selected (and focus leaves the ComboBox), it updates the Grid to only display the chosen column.

**Figure 1: On load (displays all columns)**

[image]

**Figure 2: ComboBox in action**

[image]

**Figure 3: Selecting an item in the ComboBox results in the table showing only that column**

[image]